# How to accurately track GPU VRAM usage?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, vram

I want to know how much `GPU VRAM` each line of program will occupy. When I input 224x224x3 image to VGG16, the total parameters are 138,364,968. Each parameter can store dtype float32, then total VRAM usage that the code `model.to("cuda")` run should be spend `138364986*4(bytes)/1024**2=527.820534 MB`.

**When I use this code:**

```py
def get_gpu_memory_usage():
    result = subprocess.check_output(['nvidia-smi', '--query-gpu=memory.used', '--format=csv,noheader,nounits'])
    return int(result.decode().strip())
```

**Catch each line like this:**

```py
model.to(device)
line1_memory = get_gpu_memory_usage() - initial_gpu_memory
line_memory_usage.append(line1_memory)
```

This line `model.to(device)` consumes 1125MB of VRAM usage.  I think it should consume 527.820534 MB. Do I miss something?

Comment: It stores more than those numbers. Number is not only "number" it is also reference to memory for example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Does this mean that float32 does not only occupy 4 bytes of memory capacity? Instead, it occupies 5 bytes or something?

Comment: Thanks to people who spent time reading my issue, I'm curious why I am getting minus point? Please tell me that I can fix my content. Thanks!

Comment: No, the program needs to store information about its variables, for example. Not to mention other things needed to run the code... 
In short: You arent calculating how much memory that line occupies...